# Web Service/Client relationship in Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer

Tags: visual-studio, web-services

Can you create a web service/client relationship in Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer over 2 PC's - 1 as the web service, the other as the client? If so how do you do it?

I have create this relation ship on 1 PC running both the Web service and the client, I want to send data between 2 PC's if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can! You can deploy your webservice on Server1 and then, in your solution, you right-click on the project and select "Add Web Reference". A popup asks you to choose the URL of the webservice, put the URL of the service on Server1.

More help on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355036.aspx